# Promotion in integer arithmetic expressions

Tags: c, integer-arithmetic

I have two related questions:

1. What does the standard say, and what do different compilers do, when it comes to comparison between arithmetic expression of the form x * y == z (or x + y == z), where x * y is too large for either x or y to hold, but not larger than z.
2. What about comparison between signed and unsigned integers of equal width with the same underlying binary value?

The example below may clarify what I mean

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    uint8_t x = 250;
    uint8_t y = 5;
    uint16_t z = x*y;
    uint8_t w = x*y;

    if (x * y == z)            // true
        puts ("x*y = z");
    if ((uint16_t)x * y == z)  // true
        puts ("(uint16_t)x*y = z");
    if (x * y == (uint8_t)z)   // false
        puts ("x*y = (uint8_t)z");
    if (x * y == w)            // false
        puts ("x*y = w");
    if ((uint8_t)(x * y) == w) // true
        puts ("(uint8_t)x*y = w");
    if (x * y == (uint16_t)w)  // false
        puts ("x*y = (uint16_t)w");

    int8_t X = x;
    if (x == X)                // false
        puts ("x = X");
    if (x == (uint8_t)X)       // true
        puts ("x = (uint8_t)X");
    if ((int8_t)x == X)        // true
        puts ("(int8_t)x = X");
    if (memcmp (&x, &X, 1) == 0) // true
        puts ("memcmp: x = X");
}
```

The first part does not surprise me: as explained in [Which variables should I typecast when doing math operations in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245740/which-variables-should-i-typecast-when-doing-math-operations-in-c-c) the compiler implicitly promotes shorter to longer integers during arithmetic operations (and I suppose this applies to comparison operators). Is this the guaranteed standard behaviour?

But the answer to that question, as well as the answer to [Signed/unsigned comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons) , say that signed integers should be promoted to unsigned. I was expecting that `x == X` above would be true, since they hold the same data (see `memcmp`). What seems to happen instead is that both are promoted to wider integers and then the signed-to-unsigned (or vice versa) happens.

### EDIT 2:

In particular I am interested in cases where say a function returns `int` that will be -1 in case of error, otherwise will represent e.g. number of bytes written, which should always be positive. Standard functions of this type return `ssize_t`, which if I'm not mistaken on most platforms is same as `int64_t`, but the number of bytes written can be all the way to `UINT64_MAX`. So if I want to compare the returned `int` or `ssize_t` to an unsigned value for expected bytes written, an explicit cast to `unsigned int` or `size_t` (if I'm not mistaken same width as `ssize_t` but unsigned) is needed?

---

### EDIT 1:

I can't make sense of the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (void)
{
    int8_t ssi = UINT8_MAX;
    uint8_t ssu = ssi;
    printf ("ssi = %hhd\n", ssi); // -1
    printf ("ssu = %hhu\n", ssu); // 255
    if (ssi == ssu) // false
        puts ("ssi == ssu");

    puts ("");
    int16_t si = UINT16_MAX;
    uint16_t su = si;
    printf ("si = %hd\n", si); // -1
    printf ("su = %hu\n", su); // 65535
    if (si == su) // false
        puts ("si == su");

    puts ("");
    int32_t i = UINT32_MAX;
    uint32_t u = i;
    printf ("i = %d\n", i); // -1
    printf ("u = %u\n", u); // 4294967295
    if (i == u)   // true????
        puts ("i == u");

    puts ("");
    int64_t li = UINT64_MAX;
    uint64_t lu = li;
    printf ("li = %ld\n", li); // -1
    printf ("lu = %lu\n", lu); // 18446744073709551615
    if (li == lu) // true
        puts ("li == lu");
}
```

While the 64-bit example may be explained by the fact that there is no wider integer to go to, the 32-bit one is counter-intuitive. Shouldn't it be the same as the 8- and 16-bit cases?

Comment: The wheels already fell off at `int8_t X = x;`.  You're trying to stuff an  unsigned eight-bit value of 250 into something that taps out at 127. The opposite (stuffing a signed into unsigned) has clear conversion rules (add max-type-val +1 until it falls in range), but you're doing the opposite.

Comment: Why is it undefined? I was under the impression that 250 will be cast to int8_t which would be -6. printing the value of `X` (as signed) does indeed show -6.

Comment: Not undefined, [but implementation-defined](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p3).

Comment: So the answer to "What does the standard say?" is "nothing"? And explicit casting on either side of the comparison in `X == x` must be used?

Comment: I am not sure where you got "nothing". The Standard has plenty to say; but this question may be too broad. In any case, note that the integer promotions can't be avoided. With, e.g. `(uint16_t)x * y`, and assuming 32 bit `int`, the multiplication is still carried out with `int` types, and the comparison in `(uint16_t)x * y == z` is also carried out with `int` types.

Comment: Again, with `int8_t ssi = UINT8_MAX;` you have implementation-defined behavior. See the link in my first comment.

Comment: @DavidBowling I think that may explain the edit I just posted. So when we are comparing `uint32_t` (which has the same size as `int`) and `int32_t` (same as `int` on my platform), the result is different and explicit cast is needed?

Comment: In a comparison between `uint32_t` and `int32_t`, the signed operand is converted to the unsigned type, but first the integer promotions are applied. If `int` is the same size as `int32_t` the operands will both be converted to `int` if that will hold both values, otherwise to `unsigned int` if needed. You may cast to a larger type if you want.

Comment: @DavidBowling Yes, that clears things up. I think you originally asked what the purpose of a cast would be, see my Edit #2 above.

Comment: Edit 2 should be a new question. But your code will look like `ssize_t x = foo(); if ( x < 0 ) { errorhandling } else if ( x == expected_unsigned_value )` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be mindful that prior code to the comapre like `uint8_t x = 250; ... int8_t X = x;` is implementation defined [@David Bowling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47445723/promotion-in-integer-arithmetic-expressions/47447009#comment81847140_47445723)

> 1. comparison between arithmetic expression of the form x * y == z (or x + y == z), where x * y is too large for either x or y to hold, but not larger than z.

The product of `x * y` is computed without any regard to `z`.  The product's type is determined by 1) both `x` and `y` go through the *integer promotions* to `int` or `unsigned`.   2) If the types differ, the one of lesser *rank* goes through *usual arithmetic conversions* to the higher one, then the product is calculated.  If that product numerically overflows the target type, then *undefined behavior* in the case of signed types and wrap-around in the case of unsigned types.

After the product is calculated, the compare occurs following same rules of *usual integer promotions* and then higher rank.

> 2. What about comparison between signed and unsigned integers of equal width with the same underlying binary value?

The 2 arguments, independently  go through the *integer promotions*.  If they differ in sign-ness, then the one that is signed is converted to the matching unsigned type.  Then the values are compared.

Any 2 same binary **values** will always compare same.  *After* the __integer promotions_, any 2 same binary **bit patterns** (not counting the rare padding bits) of the same width,   will compare same if the signed type is the common 2's complement.

```
int8_t i = -1;
uint8_t u = i;         // u =  255
if (i == u) --> false  // both i,x promoted to int and -1 != 255)

int i = -1;
unsigned u = i;        // u = UINT_MAX  
if (i == u) --> true   // i promoted to unsigned and value UINT_MAX
```

Comment: There is *integer promotions* and *usual arithmetic conversions*

Comment: @M.M Yes that sounds correct.  Answer amened. Edit if you see other short-comings.